# How to load 4GB XML in PHP for open street map?

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb, openstreetmap

We are using open street map data for storing cities and places (local). And open streen map OSM file is 4GB.

And we are using below mentioned code to load content and parse.

```
$this->xml = file_get_contents($file);
$xml = simplexml_load_string($this->xml);
```

But, after loading and give input to simplexml_load_string function, process gets killed.

I want to ask 2 thing:

- How to process large OSM files in PHP?
- Is there any way to DUMP OSM data file in DB MongoDB/MySQL for searching.

Comment: Use http://php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php

Comment: Processing this file in PHP is the wrong approach. Instead to some pre-processing by extracting only the information your are interested in, e.g. with [osmium](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool/) or osmosis. Afterwards you can try to process it in PHP.

Comment: @scai Yeah, I filter out my result from parent OSM file (extract cities). Still, dataset is too large and Server killed script.

Comment: Your second suggestion seems more valid: convert the OSM data to SQL and query it off an SQL server after creating indexes.